# Sending message to Twitter followers from facebook app

Tags: php, twitter

I have created a facebook app.Is it possible  to send message to twitter followers from facebook app using PHP.Is it  violation of facebook rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to start would probably be the Twitter API docs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs

There are a lot of examples on how to post to twitter using PHP and OAuth:
http://tips4php.net/2010/12/twitter-oauth-the-easy-way-simple-post-to-twitter-script/